# Error while uploading a video to Firebase, indicating that the service is currently unavailable

Tags: flutter, firebase, file-upload, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

While attempting to upload a video to Firebase, I received an error message stating "Firebase Error uploading a video the service is currently unavailable this is most likely a transient condition and may be corrected by retrying with backoff". My app user authentication worked perfectly but when user try to upload Video to Firebase Firestore it throw the error as notification from Firebase. as i understand there is no error in my app because the error show with out breaking my app any idea why this happen? Thank you for your time

I debuged my app so many times.  there is no error or warning that relate to firebase, i have no idea why this error happen

here my code for uploading function

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:ethitok/constants.dart';
import 'package:ethitok/models/video.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

import 'package:video_compress/video_compress.dart';

class UploadVideoController extends GetxController {
  _compressVideo(String videoPath) async {
    final compressedVideo = await VideoCompress.compressVideo(
      videoPath,
      quality: VideoQuality.MediumQuality,
    );
    return compressedVideo!.file;
  }

  Future<String> _uploadVideoToStorage(String id, String videoPath) async {
    Reference ref = firebaseStorage.ref().child('videos').child(id);

    UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(await _compressVideo(videoPath));
    TaskSnapshot snap = await uploadTask;
    String downloadUrl = await snap.ref.getDownloadURL();
    return downloadUrl;
  }

  _getThumbnail(String videoPath) async {
    final thumbnail = await VideoCompress.getFileThumbnail(videoPath);
    return thumbnail;
  }

  Future<String> _uploadImageToStorage(String id, String videoPath) async {
    Reference ref = firebaseStorage.ref().child('thumbnails').child(id);
    UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(await _getThumbnail(videoPath));
    TaskSnapshot snap = await uploadTask;
    String downloadUrl = await snap.ref.getDownloadURL();
    return downloadUrl;
  }

  // upload video
  uploadVideo(String songName, String caption, String videoPath) async {
    try {
      String uid = firebaseAuth.currentUser!.uid;
      DocumentSnapshot userDoc =
          await firestore.collection('users').doc(uid).get();
      // get id
      var allDocs = await firestore.collection('videos').get();
      int len = allDocs.docs.length;
      String videoUrl = await _uploadVideoToStorage("Video $len", videoPath);
      String thumbnail = await _uploadImageToStorage("Video $len", videoPath);

      Video video = Video(
        username: (userDoc.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>)['name'],
        uid: uid,
        id: "Video $len",
        likes: [],
        commentCount: 0,
        shareCount: 0,
        songName: songName,
        caption: caption,
        videoUrl: videoUrl,
        profilePhoto: (userDoc.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>)['profilePhoto'],
        thumbnail: thumbnail,
      );

      await firestore.collection('videos').doc('Video $len').set(
            video.toJson(),
          );
      Get.back();
    } catch (e) {
      Get.snackbar(
        'Error Uploading Video',
        e.toString(),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you share the code for the same?

Comment: where do i send you the code my app is written with flutter

Comment: you can paste the code in your question

Comment: check out now i edited it.

Comment: what line are you getting the error? can you also share the stacktrace?